# How to achieve header, footer and pages features like MS-office document in tinyMCE/ckeditor?

Tags: node.js, angular, ckeditor, tinymce, summernote

My application users can import ms-office document (docx) content to the editor(tinyMCE/Ckeditor) or export the editor content to docx. So the problem is, Header and footer of docx will not behave as such.

Added i want docx pages functionality into the editor like page 1, page 2 and etc.,

I have tried with document editor functionality on Ckeditor - https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/#document, but it is not satisfying my expectation.

My application is with Angular 7 and Node JS.

can somebody give me alternate solution to achieve this kind of functionality.